# Rounded corners in a table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create rounded corners for my 3 column table (CSS table). I used:

```css
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
```

in my CSS, but what I get is the top image. What I want it to look like is the bottom image.

[image: Table with rounded corners]

Is there any way that this can be done?

Comment: Can you post the CSS and HTML?

Comment: Thanks guys! nth child technique helps and this works   :nth-child(1) {
        -moz-border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
        border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

nth-child(3) {
        -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
        border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

Comment: sorry about the code indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest enclosing the whole table in a `<div>` and then rounding the corners of that div

Answer (score 3):

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1920098)

```
table { border-radius:10px; }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do each row, use the CSS pseudo-classes `:first-child` and `:last-child`.

[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/R792K/

CSS:

```css
table { border-spacing: 0; }

td {
    border-top: 1px solid black;  
    border-left: 1px solid black;  
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;  
    padding: 10px;       
}

td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;    
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;    
}

td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;    
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;    
    border-right: 1px solid black;  
}   ​
```

HTML:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>​
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TD:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

TD:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```